# Problemas ao adicionar script dinamicamente com Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Estou com problema no momento de adicionar um Script dinamicamente em uma página.

O Script que eu quero adicionar é do *CKEDITOR* (Editor de texto).

Estou conseguindo adicionar o Script, porém não consigo acessar o objeto deste Script após esta ação, o objeto que é criado é o *CKEDITOR*.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");          

script.type = "text/javascript";                        

script.async = true; // Testei  true e false e nada!            

script.src = "objs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js";           

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Quando eu tento imprimir o objeto, a mensagem que retorna é de objeto não definido.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Esse ficheiro `ckeditor.js` exporta para o espaço global? qual é o objeto que estás a tentar aceder e como?

Comment: @Sergio após a página totalmente carrega exporta o objeto CKEDITOR, mas antes da página terminar de carregar eu uso este código para exbir os objetos do document 
    for( objeto in window ){
console.log(objeto);
} mas o CKEDITOR não consta neste momento, apenas depois.

Comment: se fizeres `console.log(window.CKEDITOR);` dentro da função callback que o TobyMosque sugeriu, o que te dá?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você adiciona um script a pagina, você deve esperar que a mesma seja carregada antes de poder utilizar a mesma.

Desta forma, você deve definir uma função que será chamada apenas apos a conclusão do carregamento do script.

```
var getScript = function(url, callback)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

então para chamar adicionar o script, faça o seguinte:

```
getScript('objs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js', function () {
    //aqui o seu script já está carregado, então você já pode acessar as funções e variaveis do mesmo.
});
```

Comment: obrigado, o script carrega mas não consigo acessar pelo console o objeto gerado pelo script. Após o documento ser totalmente carregado a ferramenta carrega mas em tempo de execução quando tento usar o console.log(CKEDITOR) .

antes de terminar o carregamento da página eu estou usando o código  for( objeto in window ){console.log(objeto);} mas o objeto CKEDITOR não está carregado.

Comment: CKEDITOR é declarado dentro da função?

Comment: @RenanSantos se fizeres `console.log(window.CKEDITOR);` __dentro__ da função callback que o TobyMosque sugeriu, o que te dá?

Comment: @Sergio, acredito que ele está tentando acessar uma variavel fora do escopo da função.